# Typescript interface for elliptic

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to create a typescript interface for the elliptic library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic

I've read the docs over here, but apparently I'm just getting it.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html

The JS is normally used as follows:

```
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
var key = ec.genKeyPair();
var key = ec.keyFromPublic(pub, 'hex');
```

I feel like I've tried so many combinations at this point that I'd just be confusing this post to show you what I've tried.

The two functions shown are the only ones that I need to call genKeyPair() & keyFromPublic().

Could someone please get me started with a definition file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in a file called `elliptic-types.ts`:

```
declare module "elliptic" {
    type CurvePreset = 'secp256k1'
        | 'p192'
        | 'p224'
        | 'p256'
        | 'p384'
        | 'p521'
        | 'curve25519'
        | 'ed25519'
    ;

    class EllipticCurve {
        constructor(preset: CurvePreset);
        genKeyPair(): any;
        keyFromPublic(publicKey: string, type: 'hex'): any;
    }

    export {
        EllipticCurve as ec
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
import "./elliptic-types";
import * as elliptic from "elliptic";
var EC = elliptic.ec;
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
var key = ec.genKeyPair();
var key = ec.keyFromPublic(pub, 'hex');
```

Note that I just glanced at the README.md for the repo, which is how I got the curve presets.  I didn't see what either function was actually returning, so I returned `any`.  You'll probably want to improve on that, since `any` is generally bad.

Comment: Thank you so much. Somehow it's always so simple when you know the answer :)